# To open “MultiBit” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime

Tags: multibit, mac

I am unable to resolve this. I have updated Java but it appears to require a previous version. Thank you.

Comment: You should send this to the Multibit team https://multibit.org/

Comment: Are you using OS X?

Comment: We need a lot more details. We can't help without knowing OS (Win, Mac?), Multibit version, java version etc etc

Comment: I know for a fact Java 6 is not needed. I run it with Java 8 without any problem. Do you have any error message or something that might help us find the real problem?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using OS X, you can just double click

/Applications/MultiBit.app/Contents/Resources/Java/multibit-exe.jar

works on OS X 10.10.1, Java 7 Update 71.

guess they need some minor adjust for less strict JVM/JRE version check...

Answer (score 0):

No it works with the latest version, you need to uninstall java completely and install again.